# How can I merge two SQL tables and then append the result to a third?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following three tables:

Table 1

```
ID NAME
 1 John
```

Table 2

```
ID   ITEM
 1  apple
 2 orange
 3 banana
```

Table 3

```
ID NAME   ITEM
 1 Mike  mango
 2 Mike  grape
```

What is the most efficient way using SQL to merge Tables 1 and 2 together and append the result to Table 3 in order to get the following result (but leave 1 and 2 as they are)?

Table 3 after operation

```
ID NAME   ITEM
  1 Mike  mango
  2 Mike  grape
  3 John  apple
  4 John orange
  5 John banana
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert a cross join between the 2.
But don't insert those that already exist in table 3.

```
insert into "Table 3" (name, item) 
select t1.name, t2.item
from "Table 1" as t1
cross join "Table 2" as t2
where not exists (
  select 1
  from "Table 3" t3
  where t3.name = t1.name
    and t3.item = t2.item
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join` with `union all`:

```
select row_number() over (order by t.name, t.item) id, t.* from (
    select t2.name, t2.item from table2 t2
    union all
    select t1.name, t3.item from table1 t1 cross join table3 t3) t
```